# Recursive function for detailCellRendererParams, Ag-Grid?

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have data which consists of multiple rows of data. Each row contains a 'children' array property, which may have data in the form of more rows, or may be empty. On top of that, each of the rows within the 'children' array property may also contain more 'children' data or rows and so on, so it looks like this (think of each line as a row and each indented line as a child row of that row):

```
r|-------
 r1|------*
   r1a|------
   r1b|------*
      r1b1|------
   r1c|------*
      r1c1|------
      r1c2|------
 r2|------
 r3|------*
   r3a|------
   r3b|------
```

Each parent containing child rows (I marked them with '*') must have detailCellRendererParams defined, which is fine if I was just going to define each one manually ([as shown in Ag-Grid documentation under Nesting Master / Detail](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/), however, it is uncertain how many parent/children rows there will be. I am looking to create a recursive function that defines the detailCellRendererParams for each parent row with children. How might I write something like this?

Answer (score 0):

No recursion required, just use the tree data functionality of ag-grid:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree-data/

You need to enable tree functionality with:

```
var gridOptions = {
    treeData: true,
    ...
}
```

and provide the grid with the field that creates your tree-hierarchy

```
gridOptions.getDataPath: function(data) {
   return data.myHierarchyField;
},
```